# Get node url alias/path when loading the node using node_load()

Tags: 7, nodes, path-aliases

Does the `node_load()` does not return the node url alias in the node object or am I missing something.

I know one way of getting the url alias/path is using the `drupal_get_path_alias("node/NODE_ID")`, however I was hoping the object return by node_load should contain node url alias as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the URL alias is not a field nor entity property, and it doesn't get added to the node object when it's loaded.

It would be trivial to add that data though, using [`hook_node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7)

```
function MYMODULE_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->url_alias = url("node/$node->nid");
  } 
}
```